# JavaScript: Filter Array Elements/Objects

Tags: javascript

All I'm trying to do is filter a list of stores, store it in a new variable object called grapefruitStores, and print it to the console in JavaScript.  I'm allowed to use filter, map, and reduce.  Here's what I have so far:

```
const stores = [{
   name: "Kents",
   foods: [
       {name: 'bagels', type: 'grain'},
       {name: 'bread', type: 'grain'},
       {name: 'cereal', type: 'grain'},
       {name: 'milk', type: 'dairy'},
   ]
   },{
   name: "Maceys",
   foods: [
       {name: 'bagels', type: 'grain'},
       {name: 'bread', type: 'grain'},
       {name: 'cereal', type: 'grain'},
       {name: 'grapefruit', type: 'fruit'},
       {name: 'milk', type: 'dairy'},
   ]
}];

//Filtering code

function sellsGrapefruit(stores) {
   return stores.foods.name === 'grapefruit'; //Don't think this is correct.
}

var grapefruitStores = store.filter(sellsGrapefruit);

console.log(grapefruitStores);
```

So, only the Maceys object information should print to the console since Maceys sells grapefruit and Kents does not.  An empty array/object keeps printing to the screen, and I'm not sure why.  What am I doing wrong here?  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `foods` is array in each one...an array can't have a property `name`. Need to iterate the `foods` array

Comment: Yeah, I figured.  How would I do that?

Comment: Filter will iterate over them for you. `store.foods.filter(function(food) { return food.name === 'grapefruit'; })`

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`Array.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some):

```
function sellsGrapefruit(store) {
    return store.foods.some(function(food) {
        return food.name === 'grapefruit';
    });
};

var grapefruitStores = stores.filter(sellsGrapefruit);
```

Comment: In this case, I don't think they're allowed to. 
"I'm allowed to use filter, map, and reduce."

Comment: Thank you, @Washington Guedes!

Comment: I like your answer. I was not aware of the Array.some() function.

Answer (score 0):

So this is pretty simple with the `filter` method. What this does is include elements from an array depending on the boolean return value of the function passed to it. You're almost there with what you posted, but foods is an array of objects, each of which has a name property, and you're currently calling the (non-existent) name property of stores.

So for this example, with working iteration, a working solution would be:

```
var grapefruitStores = stores.filter(function(store) {
    for (var i = 0; i < store.foods.length; i++) {
        if (store.foods[i].name === 'grapefruit') {
            return true;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Why are you using a for loop inside filter when you can use filter again. Edit, oh to exit early. I guess that's valid, but probably besides the point of learning filter/map/reduce

Comment: Because I didn't want to use filter again? I'm not sure why you think I should use one or the other. If anything, the for loop is faster.

Comment: Thank you, @furkle!

Comment: @WashingtonGuedes Good point! And also you're right, that's a typo on my part, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There's a little flaw with your filter logic. Your algorithm is checking the `foods` attribute of the `stores` array. It should be checking the `foods` attribute of each element in the `stores` array. Try this:

```
//Filtering code
function sellsGrapefruit(store) {
  for (var i in store.foods) {
    var food = store.foods[i];
    if (food.name === 'grapefruit')
      return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

Here is a working example:

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mspinks/8vzfc8uL/3/

Answer (score 0):

Foods arrays is nested in the objects in the stores array, so you have to use the `filter` twice in order to get the result you want:

```
const stores = [{
   name: "Kents",
   foods: [
       {name: 'bagels', type: 'grain'},
       {name: 'bread', type: 'grain'},
       {name: 'cereal', type: 'grain'},
       {name: 'milk', type: 'dairy'}
   ]
   },{
   name: "Maceys",
   foods: [
       {name: 'bagels', type: 'grain'},
       {name: 'bread', type: 'grain'},
       {name: 'cereal', type: 'grain'},
       {name: 'grapefruit', type: 'fruit'},
       {name: 'milk', type: 'dairy'}
   ]
}];

function sellsGrapefruit(store) {
    var x = store.foods.filter(function(i) {
        return i.name === 'grapefruit';
    });
    return x.length > 0;
}

var grapefruitStores = stores.filter(sellsGrapefruit); // typo error: store -> stores

console.log(grapefruitStores[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're allowed to use only `map`, `reduce`, `filter`. I took this approach.

```
var grapeStores = stores.filter(function (store) {
  return store.foods.filter(function (food) {
    return food.name === 'grapefruit';
  }).length;
});

console.log('grapeStores', grapeStores);
```

It logs

```
grapeStores [ { name: 'Maceys',
    foods: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ] } ]
```